# images not showing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mithril.js

I have rendered my views using mithrilljs  like [this](http://pastebin.com/BPGTuEaK) . This is how I am rendering images

```
 m('img.u-marginbottom-10[alt=\'Icon blog\'][src=\'/assets/icon-blog.png\']')
```

This works fine in dev env but in the prod env, the image is not found. During prod, I precompile my assets. Is there a way to fix this issue with precompiling the assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images served through Asset Pipeline on production do include digest in their name, so your *icon-block.png* will actually be something like *icon-block-somefancyhash28582here.png*, you should either

- put this file in `/public/` folder,
- serve the url to it from backend
- use some kind of magical gem that allows you to use `asset_url` in your javascript files

or [disable adding digest to files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-digests-off) which is highly not recommended